# Adsupportframework works on iOS5 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, ios-simulator

Why does Adsupportframework work on my iOS5 simulator? I thought if you enabled adsupportframework as a requirement on a iOS 5 simulator it would cause the simulator to crash. When I enable the social framework this cause my iOS 5 simulator to crash which it suppose to. This is kind of bugging me.

Comment: needs some more info here...

Comment: What other information do you need?

Comment: Well how are we supposed to know why it doesn't work? If we have no code or references, we can't figure out your problem for you.

Comment: My question is why the framework "AdSupport" is working with my iOS 5 simulator when all over the internet people are saying that it isn't suppose to.

Comment: make AdSupport frame work optional to avoid crash

Answer (score 0):

AdSupport framework is introduced in iOS6. To avoid crash in device with iOS5 or below, just make it optional framework. See image reference here:

[image]